# How does the forecast function work for auto.arima with exogenous regressors?

Tags: r, dynamic, regression, forecast

I am trying to fit a dynamic regression model using auto.arima. I have monthly data for gas (for heating) use per customer (which I want to predict) and set of regressors (e.g. heating degree days, gas price, structural dummies for particular years and seasonal dummies). I have forecast values for the exogenous regressors. Use per customer data is available from Jan 2005- Mar2018, all other data is from Jan2005-Dec 2021. I am trying to forecast Use Per Customer for all months of the year 2020. 
I am unsure how to divide my data between xreg in the auto.arima function and the forecast function. The forecast values I am currently yielding do not match up with the month of use, for example, April 2018 forecast for use per customer is as high as and almost equal to Jan 2005 actual use. This should not be the case.

I am trying to forecast gas usage for residential customers using a dynamic regression model in the forecats package. I have referred to the online textbook by Prof. Rob J. Hyndman
    https://otexts.com/fpp2/forecasting.html

```
#I generated the time series for the period for which the data is available (Jan 2005-Mar 2018)
Med_ros_upc.ts.test<-ts(Med_ros_upc.ts[,"ORMEDSCH410upc.r"], 
frequency    = 12, start = c(2005,1), end = c(2018,3))                        
#This is the set of external regressors including seasonal dummies(sd.ts)
xreg_Med<- cbind(Hdd = Med_ros_upc.ts[, "MEDHDD"],
             Hdd2 = Med_ros_upc.ts[, "MEDHDD2"],
             RPA = Med_ros_upc.ts[, "ORSCH410RPAt1.r"],  sd, 
             Jan2009, intdummf)
#I convert the xreg matrix into a time series. I use this in auto.arima
xreg_Med.ts<-ts(xreg_Med, frequency = 12, start = c(2005,1), 
end = c(2018,3))
#I generate a different xreg for forecast"
xreg_Med.ts1<-ts(xreg_Med, frequency = 12, start = c(2018,4),
 end = c(2021, 12))
fitdyn <- auto.arima(Med_ros_upc.ts.test, xreg =xreg_Med.ts)
fcast <- forecast(fitdyn , xreg = xreg_Med.ts1)
```

Expected result 
             Point forecast
Jan 2005      111.19
Feb 2005      89.22...
April 2005    53.86

Actual result  Point forecast

April 2018      111.19
May 2018    89.22...
Jun 2018    53.86

Answer (score 0):

Your training data starts in Jan 2005 and finishes in March 2018. So your forecasts start in April 2018. Forecasts are future to the training data by definition.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was hoping to see fitted values from 2005-2018 and the forecast for a few years beyond that. I am mostly interested in having the forecast for year 2020. Would you know of any other function that would generate the fitted values and the forecast? Thanks again!

Comment: fitted() generates fitted values. forecast() has an argument to determine the forecast horizon.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
This is what I did:

```
`fitdyn <- auto.arima(Med_ros_upc.ts[,"ORMEDSCH410upc.r"], xreg =xreg_Med, stationary= TRUE)`
`fit<-fitted(fitdyn)`
`fcast_fit<-forecast(fit, h=36, xreg= xreg_Med)`
```

Now I have two separate tables, one with the fitted values and with the forecast, and the values look alright.

However, I am getting this error message:

**Error in etsmodel(y, errortype[i], trendtype[j], seasontype[k], damped[l],  : 
  unused argument (xreg = xreg_Med)
In addition: Warning message:
In ets(object, lambda = lambda, biasadj = biasadj, allow.multiplicative.trend = allow.multiplicative.trend,  :
  Missing values encountered. Using longest contiguous portion of time series**

Does this mean that the forecast I am obtaining does not account for the external regressors?

Comment: Hi there! You posted this as an answer but it looks like it should be a question or a comment.

Comment: Yes you are right. I will repost it as a question. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I ran the following but it has an error message:

Comment: `fitdyn <- auto.arima(Med_ros_upc.ts[,"ORMEDSCH410upc.r"], xreg =xreg_Med, stationary= TRUE)`
    `fit<-fitted(fitdyn)`
    `fcast_fit<-forecast(fit, h=36, xreg= xreg_Med)`

**Error in etsmodel(y, errortype[i], trendtype[j], seasontype[k], damped[l],  : 
  unused argument (xreg = xreg_Med)
In addition: Warning message:
In ets(object, lambda = lambda, biasadj = biasadj, allow.multiplicative.trend = allow.multiplicative.trend,  :
  Missing values encountered. Using longest contiguous portion of time series**  Does this mean external regressiors are not included in the forecast?